# make gradient background with tailwind css

Tags: css, tailwind-css, gradient

i am struggling to make a background like this [![enter image description here][1]][1]

i tried this

```
     <div className="relative bg-gradient-to-br from-[#23486F] via-[#192532] to- 
      [#10131C] w-screen h-screen">
     <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-br from-black via-transparent to- 
     black opacity-50" />
     </div>
```

but i am not getting the result i just need the background not the other elements want so any help please ?

Comment: you mean you want circular gradient ?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For circular gradient, try `radial-gradient`.

Something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-screen w-screen bg-[radial-gradient(ellipse_at_center,_var(--tw-gradient-stops))] from-[#23486F] via-[#192532] to-[#10131C]"></div>
```

Here is an usefull tool to play with gradient, check [hypercolor](https://hypercolor.dev/generator), for more example.